# UITable view Should like an MSExcel Sheet

Tags: uitableview

I am new to Objective-C programming .I want the the UITABLEVIEW data which is presented in  TABLEVIEW should look similar MSExcel excel sheet .can anybody  help me please please.For Example the top of table should strong text look like this for employee details

```
 EmpName EMPId EmpAge EmpGender EmpPhoneNumber 
 JACKSON 1244   23      M       089542635
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To precisely mimic an excel spreadsheet, you should probably write your own custom control, probably not based on UITableView, since you'd want horizontal scrolling in addition to vertical scrolling.

If you still want to try to force UITableView to do what you want, then create a custom header view and return it form the method viewForHeaderInSection: method to get your "top of table" line, and create custom UITableViewCells and fill them in with data, or for a simpler option just format multiple columns of data into each cell's "textLabel" label.